# Convert from JComboBox to JTextField

Tags: java, swing

```
 origPrice * discCombo = salesPrice;
```

I understand this would be problem. As I have tried to convert the JComboBox to a JTextField and that will not work. I cannot find online how to do that. Can someone please help out with this.

origPrice is a jtextfield, and discombo is the combo box, and the salesPrice is also a jtextfield. I want to be able to multiple what the user puts in for the original price and then multiply it by the selected item they get from the drop down combobox and then it results into the salesPrice jtextfield

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking here, please try to develop by adding a context and what have you tried already and how it did not worked

Comment: JCombobox can't be converted to JTextField.However you can set thier contents.Also mention that which one is the JTextField.if the 'salesPrice' is JTextField then you have to do like this.
salesPrice.setText((Integer)discCombo.getSelectedItem())*origPrice+"";

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to convert the JComboBox into anything as your far better off leaving it alone and simply extracting the data that it holds when you desire. This can be done via `getSelectedItem()`, checking that it's not null, and then using it.

For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboDemo extends JPanel {
   private Integer[] items = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
   private DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items);
   private JComboBox<Integer> combo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
   private JFormattedTextField orgPriceField = new JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("0.00")); 
   private JFormattedTextField finalPriceField = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());

   public ComboDemo() {
      finalPriceField.setFocusable(false);
      orgPriceField.setColumns(10);
      finalPriceField.setColumns(10);
      orgPriceField.setText("0.00");

      add(orgPriceField);
      add(new JLabel("x"));
      add(combo);
      add(new JLabel("="));
      add(finalPriceField);

      add(new JButton(new CalculateAction()));
   }

   private class CalculateAction extends AbstractAction {

      public CalculateAction() {
         super("Calculate");
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Number orgPrice = (Number) orgPriceField.getValue();
         Integer multiplier = ((Integer) comboModel.getSelectedItem()).intValue();

         double result = orgPrice.doubleValue() * multiplier;
         finalPriceField.setValue(result);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ComboDemo mainPanel = new ComboDemo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboDemo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```